# getting hour part and time-zone part from datetime

Tags: c#

I had a string in config file, defining date time with time zone.
I am not able to get this value, while reading values from config file.

In config file:

```
Setting name="abcdefgh" value="2012-08-10T22:00:00-08:00"
```

In C#, I am reading this as follows:

```
 DateTime StartDate;

 StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("abcdefgh"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
            Configuration.Instance.abcdefgh= StartDate;
```

In start date, i am getting 11 Aug, 2012 11:30:00, with no time zone.

I want to read it as it is. also tell, if my format of writing datetime in config file is correct

Comment: You haven't included the config file. DateTime does not contain timezone information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN link to [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx).

> Use DateTimeOffset whenever you are referring to an exact point in
>   time.  For example, use it to calculate "now", transaction times, file
>   change times, logging event times, etc.  If the time zone is not
>   known, use it with UTC.  These uses are much more common than the
>   scenarios where DateTime is preferred, so this should be considered
>   the default.

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-08-10T22:00:00-08:00");
date.Offset // -08:00:00,  offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
date.DateTime // 10/08/2012 22:00:00,
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime doesn't keep information about timezone. To parse the string and keep information about timezone - you should use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure (and `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`) if you want to store timezone information.

Your ParseExact format also doesn't quite match the setting value: it should have a zz at the end for the timezone information. You can also use `DateTimeOffset.Parse` since your setting string is in a standard format.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard format, so the ParseExact isn't needed, try:

```
StartDate = DateTime.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("abcdefgh"));
```

I substituted the hard-coded value you provided and got the correct result for my timezone (GMT-4) as

> 8/11/2012 2:00 AM

**Note:** as others mentioned, the timezone is not retained, so you will get the correct localized time corresponding to whatever timezone information was in the string, but you won't be able to find out what timezone that was.  The `DateTime.Kind` property will reflect that it's a local time.